# JavaFX 8 DatePicker style

Tags: java, css, datepicker, javafx

How to change the style of the calendar in the DatePicker in JavaFX 8? I looked in all the default styles in modena file and i don't find the classes of the DatePicker. Anyone knows how to do it? For example, change the header color to blue.

The default style is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the css for the `DatePicker`control under `.date-picker` and `.date-picker-popup` style classes on the modena.css file.

If you want to change the header (I guess you mean the upper pane with Month and Year), this is what you need:

```
.date-picker-popup > .month-year-pane {
    -fx-padding: 0.588883em 0.5em 0.666667em 0.5em; /* 7 6 8 6 */
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-box-border,30%), 
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-base,-3%), 
                                   derive(-fx-base,5%) 50%, 
                                   derive(-fx-base,-3%));
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0;
}
```

You just need to add this style class to your css file, and change `-fx-base` to the color you want.

Comment: Thank you very much !, what happened is that I was reviewing an online modena.css file and that file is incomplete. Thanks  again:)