# How to change background color of JavaFX 8 DatePicker's text field?

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

How one can change background color of DatePicker's text field? I tried `-fx-background-color: color;` but it only change something "below" desired text field.

Comment: which datepicker you are using, also can you show html or something else

Comment: this might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597919/javafx-8-datepicker-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an external CSS file, do

```
.date-picker .text-field {
    -fx-control-inner-background: yellow ;
}
```